# Ansible Loop within the same loop using with_items

Tags: loops, ansible, nested-loops

Looking for help trying to loop through multiple pools while some pools may have more than 1 host.
I've attempted to do `with_nested` and `with_subelements` but both don't seem to do what I want.

```
- name: Pool members
  bigip_pool_member:
    state: present
    pool: "{{ item.pool }}"
    partition: Common
    host: "{{ item.host }}"
    port: "{{ item.port }}"
    provider:
      server: bigip.domain.com
      user: admin
      password: admin
      validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items:
    - { pool: pool, host: [10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11], port: 80 }
    - { pool: pool2, host: 10.10.10.10, port: 80 }
```

I believe the host field can only take one value at a time, so I need to loop through the hosts for one pool. The output would be something along the lines of

```
  bigip_pool_member:
    state: present
    pool: pool
    partition: Common
    host: 10.10.10.10
    port: 80

  bigip_pool_member:
    state: present
    pool: pool
    partition: Common
    host: 10.10.10.11
    port: 80

  bigip_pool_member:
    state: present
    pool: pool2
    partition: Common
    host: 10.10.10.10
    port: 80
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to loop, given your code snippet here in order to get some suitable answers. Also please add some sentences about what was the behavior you expected from your first two attempts and what did you observe why your attempts were not suited to fulfill your desired task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html#subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries) is what you're looking for. For example, see the playbook below how to reference the attributes you need

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_pools:
      - {pool: pool, host: [10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11], port: 80}
      - {pool: pool2, host: [10.10.10.10], port: 80}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "pool:{{ item.0.pool }} port:{{ item.0.port }} host:{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_pools }}"
        - host
```

give

```
    "msg": "pool:pool port:80 host:10.10.10.10"
    "msg": "pool:pool port:80 host:10.10.10.11"
    "msg": "pool:pool2 port:80 host:10.10.10.10"
```

Notes

- Simply put the references to the attributes into your code.
- Be consistent. The attribute `host` must be a list even if the list has one item only.
- Use `loop` instead of `with_subelements`

```
      loop: "{{lookup('subelements', my_pools, 'host', {'skip_missing': True})}}"
```

---

Below is the task with minimal changes that should make it work

```
- name: Pool members
  bigip_pool_member:
    state: present
    pool: "{{ item.0.pool }}"
    partition: Common
    host: "{{ item.1 }}"
    port: "{{ item.0.port }}"
    provider:
      server: bigip.domain.com
      user: admin
      password: admin
      validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_subelements:
    - - {pool: pool, host: [10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.11], port: 80}
      - {pool: pool2, host: [10.10.10.10], port: 80}
    - host
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>